# Is there a way to define an piecewise function in sympy where the intervals depend on indexed symbols?

Tags: python, indexing, sympy, symbols, piecewise

As the title says. I have created an indexed symbol 't' and I wish to create a piecewise function that is (-1)^k when t[1]+t[2]+...+t[k]<=x<t[1]+t[2]+...+t[k]+t[k+1], up to a given maximum value of k=n. My code is currently as follows:

```
def SumToN(x,n):
    result = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        result += x[i]
    return result

t = sp.IndexedBase('t')
x = sp.Symbol('x')
k = sp.Symbol('k')

uFunc = sp.Piecewise(((-1)^(k-1),SumToN(t,k)<=x<SumToN(t,k+1)) for k in range(1,n+1))
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

I understand that it is having trouble with being able to confirm which region x is in, but when I try this with say 3 symbols t1, t2, and t3, I get no errors. Am I doing something clearly wrong, and is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a compound inequality with symbols, only numbers. So `1<2<3` works but `1<Symbol('x')<3` must be written as `x = Symbol('x'); And(1 < x, x < 3)`. Also, Piecewise does not work with an iterator, so try:

```py
Piecewise(*[((-1)^(k-1), And(SumToN(t,k)<=x, x<SumToN(t,k+1)))
 for k in range(1,n+1)])
```

Comment: I am continuing to get the same error. Unfortunately, I don't know of any other way to define such a function in Sympy.

Comment: You haven't provided complete code so it isn't possible to do more than just guess what the problem is.

Comment: Sam, replace your Piecewise with the Piecewise I gave you. I tested it and it created the Piecewise successfully for n=5.

Comment: I have an issue with 'NameError: name 'And' is not defined', and if I use simply 'and' inbetween the two conditions I get the same error as before. Where does this 'And' notation come from?

Comment: `from sympy import And`